# jQuery.each() does not run

Tags: jquery, count, each, html

```
$(function(){
    $(".link").each(function(){
        var spany =$('span').size();
        var word = $('.button').text().length;
        var a = 5;
        if(a > word){
            $("#control").append("small");
        } else {
            $("#control").append("big");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I have a problem with jquery and its `each` function. `each` does not run.
In my example I have second span 5 word (big) but first span 4 word (not big).
I want output 1.span small, 2.span big. How can I fix my code to get this?

http://jsfiddle.net/GNUUH/

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly, but why use the .each at all? You don't use 'this' or (index, element) parameters, so .each doesn't really have an effect...

Comment: Another five bucks that it's a repeated id :P

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, note that `.length` is preferred to the (now deprecated) `.size()`. (But if you _are_ going to use `.size()` at least use it consistently, rather than using it sometimes and `.length` other times.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".link").each(function(){
        var spany =$(this).find('span').size();
        var word = $(this).find('.button').text().length;
        var a = 5;
        if(a > word){
            $("#control").append("small");
        } else {
            $("#control").append("big");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

i hope this would help

Answer (score 1):

Your current selectors for `span` and `.button` will search the entire document.  Use `$(this).find` to only search below the current `.link` element:

```
var spany = $(this).find('span').size();
var word = $(this).find('.button').text().length;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNUUH/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You're going through every span on the page for each itereation of the each loop.

Check this solution out...
http://jsfiddle.net/GNUUH/7/